# ImageMap in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5

I'm trying to get ImageMap funcionality in SAPUI5.

I've done html and core:html tags - it works fine, i can press on areas I'm interested in but it didn't solve my problem since I wasn't able to create custom press event on specific areas.

I need to perform different actions depending on which part of image someone clicked.

I'd like to get to know if there's ImageMap and Area equivalent in UI5 (it was in sap.ui.commons but that library is depreciated).

Comment: Which view you have used it,  XML or JS ?

Comment: @inizio XML view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve by attaching the *Click* event listener and *custom data* to the `area` tags

- XML view using custom class (areaMap) and custom data (data-areaSelected) to the `area` tags

**XML View**

```
<l:VerticalLayout class="sapUiContentPadding" width="100%">
  <l:content>
    <core:HTML content='&lt;img usemap="#aus-nz" src="assets/images/map.gif" width="200" height="142" alt="Map of Australia & New Zealand"&gt; &lt;map name="aus-nz"&gt;
      &lt;area class="areaMap" shape="poly" coords="3,47,45,12,105,7,140,60,120,125,12,90" data-areaSelected="Aus" alt="Australia"&gt;
      &lt;area class="areaMap" shape="poly" coords="180,85,200,98,167,142,157,138" data-areaSelected="NewZld" alt="New Zealand"&gt;
    &lt;/map&gt;' />
  </l:content>
</l:VerticalLayout>
```

- Initialize  the *click* event listeners to area tags and once the area is clicked the corresponding area custom data will be used to take the action

**Controller.js**

```
onAfterRendering: function() {
  this.initializeEventListener(this); 
},
initializeEventListener: function(that) {
  const aAreas = document.querySelectorAll('area.areaMap');
  aAreas.forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener('click', function(oEvent) { //Attach click event listener to areas
    that.takeAction(that, oEvent.target.dataset.areaselected);
  }));
},
takeAction: function(that, selectedArea) {
    //Your code 
},
```